# Generate an iOS Project (.xcodeproj) with AppleScript

Tags: ios, applescript, xcode

How can I generate an iOS project (.xcodeproj) with AppleScript (without XCode)?

Comment: What do you mean "generate an iOS project"? What is the functionality of your desired outcome?

Comment: I wish to create an empty iOS project.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an empty iOS Xcode project once, put it somewhere on your disk, and then use an AppleScript to copy the folder (.xcodeproj is basically just a folder) to the desired destination.

(But I can't think of a single use for this...)

Comment: I am searching a solution to automate the creation of projects. Basically, I want to know what is possible to do with AppleScript.